# How to disable git in aptana? or turn it off?

Tags: git, aptana

Git in Aptana (Linux) is not valid - it shows not correct (old) information and it's not convenient for me work with it. I'm using git through command line and gitg. Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Aptana ticket #1988](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/1988-aptana-git-plugin-disable) reports:

- there was no way to disable the git integration in Studio 3 in November 2010
- there should be an option (as of March 2011) in Aptana to turn off automatic sharing.

According to [ticket APSTUD-1372](http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-1372), this option has been delivered in Aptana Sudio3 final, so try to check if the [Aptana3.0.4](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download) from 12 days ago ([2011-08-15](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/releasenotes)) would work better for you.

Answer (score 9):

You can turn off automatic git suport in Preferences->Team->Git

For enabling/disabling individual projects go to Project Explorer->right click->Team

here you can share (enable git repo) and disconnect.

hope this helps

Comment: I unchecked all the Git choices. The UI no longer shows git related updates/options, but Aptana is still doing git-things behind the scenes, e.g., sometimes pops up an error when I switch branches or interferes with rebase until I exit Aptana.

Comment: Bill, have you considered that it might not be Aptana doing git specific things, but possibly that aptana has certain files open and you are trying to change them? It usually shouldn't be a problem though, as long as you add the aptana project files to gitignore